# NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined (doc2vec similarity)

Tags: similarity, gensim, doc2vec

I have gensim installed in my system. I did the summarization with gensim. NOw I want to  find the similarity between the sentence and it showing an error. sample code is given below. I have downloaded the Google news vectors.

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

#two sample sentences
s1 = 'the first sentence'
s2 = 'the second text'
#model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('../GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
#calculate distance between two sentences using WMD algorithm
distance = model.wmdistance(s1, s2)

print ('distance = %.3f' % distance)
```

> Error#################################################
>
> ****Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/abhi/Desktop/CHiir/CLustering &
>   summarization/.idea/FInal_version/sentence_embedding.py", line 7, in
>   
>       model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz',
>   binary=True) NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined****

Answer (score 1):

Importing with `from x import y` only lets you use `y`, but not `x`.

You can either do `import gensim` instead of `from gensim.models import KeyedVectors`, or you can directly use the imported `KeyedVectors`:

```
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./data/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```